# XP 100% CPU on Login, by random processes

Tags: windows-xp, cpu-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XP 100% CPU on Login, by random processes](https://superuser.com/questions/112901/xp-100-cpu-on-login-by-random-processes)

I have a serious issue on my Windexs XP machine.

When I start it up it takes ages to login, then when I bring up task manager I find that its running at 100% CPU However, the process taking the CU are random (and there are usualy about 4 of them). They change a bit, but the CPU never drops below 100% at all.

I have to hit the reset button and try boot again to resolve the issue, usually it takes two or three times to get a login without the problem, and then I just put the machine in standby mode when I'm not using it.

I can't remember when this started happening, but its deffo more than a year ago.

Its not just services though ... Things like NetMeter or TaskbarShuffle take up the CPU ... Then whenever I kill the processes, the CPU doesn't drop below 100% for even a second as some other random process takes the CPU.

I know its not a virus ... What could it be ? Driver issue ?

Any suggested paths for resolution would be appreciated.

Cheers, Ro

Comment: How do you **know** its not a virus?  Sounds like pretty suspicious behavior to me.

Comment: I know you've given a couple of examples of the offending processes, but can you list more? There might be a pattern.

Comment: Try Soluto to see what's running when booting ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to install [Process Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer) (Sysinternals) in order to gather more information.

For instance it has a hierarchical view of processes (which process started a given process, all the way back to `System` and `explorer.exe`)

Comment: I've just Run Hijack This and Identified some Services that are perhaps unnecessary.

Will update my Video drivers also to see if they are the issue

Comment: @Ro: for information on which services can safely be eliminated I can recommend Black Viper, e.g. http://www.blackviper.com/WinXP/servicecfg.htm